# Interpolating org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate into FreeMarker

Tags: javascript, alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-webscripts

I'm developing web script for `Alfresco 5.0d CE` and encountered an issue: I cannot interpolate `datetime` value of type `org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate` in my `FreeMarker` template directly (or with embedded FreeMarker methods `?date`, `?time` or `?datetime`).

> ${var.startDate}

interpolates into

> org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate@<some_hash>

Please, advise me, how can I do that?

Comment: How are you creating the date in JS to start with?

Comment: I do not create `datetime` by myself, just receiving it through Alfresco API from `Activity` engine.

Answer (score 1):

Can you introduce your own FreeMarker utility methods in Alfresco? Because then there you can call the static `org.mozilla.javascript.Context.toType(valueFromRhyno, Date.class)` method to convert the Rhyno JavaScript date to a Java `java.util.Date`. So let's say you implement that in Java, then expose that utility to FreeMarker. I don't know how to do that in Alfresco, but FreeMarker itself supports that. Then you can do something like `${myJsUtils.toJava(var.startDate)}`.

Actually, FreeMarker's `ObjectWrapper` facility is designed to deal with these kind of mismatches. If you can use a custom `ObjectWrapper`, then it could just work magically, as then FreeMarker will know how to convert the Rhyno objects automatically. But I guess changing such a core setting under Alfrescho can be tricky. Too bad they themselves didn't do that.